# std::async using an rvalue reference bound to a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdbind

I'm trying to bind an rvalue reference to a lambda using `std::bind`, but I have issues when I throw that into a `std::async` call: ([source](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d46c1cd466e1a08))

```
auto lambda = [] (std::string&& message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
};
auto bound = std::bind(lambda, std::string{"hello world"});
auto future = std::async(bound); // Compiler error here
future.get()
```

This issues a compiler error I'm not really sure how to interpret:

> error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of(std::basic_string)>&()>'

What's going on here? Interestingly, a slight modification does compile and work as expected. If I change `std::string{"hello world"}` to a c-string literal, everything works fine: ([source](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85ae5aa256e147ea))

```
auto lambda = [] (std::string&& message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
};
auto bound = std::bind(lambda, "hello world");
auto future = std::async(bound);
future.get(); // Prints "hello world" as expected
```

Why does this work but not the first example?

Comment: It also works, if the lambda is defined with `auto lambda = [] (std::string& message)`    (reference, not rvalue)

Comment: I've noticed that as well, though it should be `const string& message`, otherwise it'll refuse to accept a c-string literal.

Comment: Just let `async` do the binding for you: `std::async(lambda, std::string{"hello world"})`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::bind` is going to make a copy of the `std::string` argument and pass that to the lambda. But that fails to compile because the lambda requires an rvalue argument, while what `bind` passes it will be an lvalue. You could get this to work if you get `bind` to `move` the argument, but this requires extremely ugly casting for disambiguation (because [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) is an overloaded function).

```
auto bound = std::bind(lambda, std::bind(static_cast<std::string&&(*)(std::string&)>(std::move),
                                         std::string{"hello world"}));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b4d0edf0df2aaf9)

You could, of course, write your own version of `move` that is not overloaded, and avoid that cast.

The second case works because when `bind` passes the `char const *` to the lambda, an rvalue `std::string` temporary is created implicitly.

---

To explain the error message you're seeing, somewhere within the innards of `std::async`, `std::result_of` is being invoked to determine the return type of the function call expression. However, because that call expression is invalid due to the reasons explained above, [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is being SFINAE'd out (this is a C++14 change). Hence the error `error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<...>'`.

Comment: Ugh. Yes, that's ugly as hell.

Comment: Very clever. Makes sense since `lambda("hello world")` would compile but `auto s = std::string{"hello world"}; lambda(s)` would not.

Comment: Another option in this case is to just create a new lambda.
`auto bound = [lambda,msg=std::string{"hello world"}]() mutable { lambda(std::move(msg)); };`

Comment: @Brian, you're right, a generalized lambda capture would obviate the need for `std::bind`. I'm restricted to C++11 at the moment though, so that won't work in my situation, but that's good to know in case C++14 does become an option.