# Difference between std::async and std::bind when wrapping rvalue reference lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, rvalue-reference, stdbind

Inspired by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084357/stdasync-using-an-rvalue-reference-bound-to-a-lambda#comment48282493_30084357) about binding lambdas with rvalue reference parameters directly to `std::async`, binding an rvalue to a lambda through `std::async` compiles and executes as expected: ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67ce1197ec9f83f8))

```
auto lambda = [] (std::string&& message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
};
auto future = std::async(lambda, std::string{"hello world"});
future.get();
```

Using `std::bind`, however, triggers a compiler error: ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ae907b688a19fa2))

```
auto lambda = [] (std::string&& message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
};
auto bound = std::bind(lambda, std::string{"hello world"}); // Compiler error
bound();
```

This is because `std::bind` keeps `message` as an lvalue, so that when it passes it to the lambda, the argument no longer matches the parameter.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14913055/2297365) that `std::async` internally uses `std::bind`, so how does it get away with rvalue reference parameters when `std::bind` does not? Is there a particular part of the standard that requires this behavior or is this dependent on the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14913055/2297365) that
>   `std::async` internally uses `std::bind`, so how does it get away with
>   rvalue reference parameters when `std::bind` does not?

It doesn't use `bind` internally. (Or rather, it couldn't without going through some epic contortions like the one in [@Praetorian's answer in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084685/2756719), and it's much easier to just write something separately).

It is usually implemented using a somewhat `bind`-like machinery, but it's much simpler because it doesn't have to handle all sorts of weird things `bind` handles (nested `bind`s, placeholders, dropping extra arguments, etc.)

> Is there a particular part of the standard that requires this behavior
>   or is this dependent on the compiler?

It's required by the standard. The specification of `bind` is ridiculously dense, but does require plain bound arguments to be passed as lvalues ([func.bind.bind]/p10, bullet 4).

`async` is specified to call `INVOKE (DECAY_COPY (std::forward<F>(f)),
DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)`, and `DECAY_COPY` always returns an rvalue.