# How to pass std::bind as universal reference type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, perfect-forwarding, stdbind

As I understand it,

1. `std::bind` perfectly forwards both the callable object it wraps and the arguments to that callable object;
2. the `std::bind` return object is itself movable and/or copyable, depending on whether the callable object and its arguments are movable and/or copyable;
3. a `std::bind` return object may be nested, in which case the outer `std::bind` return object is movable and/or copyable, just as when binding other callable objects.

Therefore, I would expect the following code snippet to compile okay. Instead, the code generates a spew of compiler errors at the last two statements in `main()`.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename HandlerType>
void call_handler(HandlerType&& handler)
{
  handler();
}

template<typename HandlerType>
void do_something(HandlerType&& handler)
{
  auto f = std::bind(
    &call_handler<HandlerType&>,
    std::forward<HandlerType>(handler));
  f();
}

int main()
{
  auto a = [&]() {};
  do_something(a);
  do_something(std::move(a));

  auto b = std::bind([&]() {});
  do_something(b);              // <- compiler error!
  do_something(std::move(b));   // <- compiler error!
}
```

Each of the two problem line spews errors without the other. To eliminate all errors, I must comment out both lines.

Here's a sample error, from g++ 4.9.2 in Cygwin, at the call to `f()` in `do_something()`:

```
(4 of 103): error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Bind<main()::<lambda()>()>))(std::_Bind<main()::<lambda()>()>&)>) ()’
```

Here's a sample error from Visual Studio 2013, at the same line:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio12.0\VC\include\functional(1149): error C2664: 'void (HandlerType)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::_Bind<false,void,main::<lambda_2b8ed726b4f655ffe5747e5b66152230>,> '
```

What's going on? Do I misunderstand `std::bind`?

Specifically, how can I

1. bind a callable object? and
2. pass that `std::bind` return object to a function taking a universal reference? and
3. nest that `std::bind` return object in another `std::bind`?

My goal is for the underlying callable object and its arguments to be perfectly forwarded.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want to pass the wrapped callable object and its arguments by value, not by reference, so `std::ref` won't help—at least, not as a full solution. The reason is that my real code is more complex and involves passing the `f` `std::bind` return object across a thread boundary, and both the `a` and `b` `std::bind` return objects may go out of scope in the original thread before `call_handler` calls `f()`, so `a` and `b` need to copy or move into `f`, not be mere references. That said, my question is specifically about `std::bind` and perfect forwarding, and for the purpose of asking a good question, I've distilled out everything not needed to reproduce the specific compiler errors I mentioned.

Comment: std::bind takes arguments by value, you may use std::ref to pass references

Comment: @Dieter I edited my question to show I specifically want to copy or move, not use references. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption 1 is wrong, `bind` always passes the bound arguments as lvalues to the callable it is wrapping. To demonstrate this, change the `bind` expression within `do_something` to the following

```
auto f = std::bind(
    &call_handler<decltype(handler)>,
    std::forward<HandlerType>(handler));
```

The following line will then fail to compile

```
do_something(std::move(a));
```

because `decltype(handler)` is an rvalue reference, but `bind` will try to call `call_handler` with an lvalue reference to the bound lambda expression you passed it in `main`.

---

Now for what's going wrong in the second half of your example. `bind` has special handling for nested `bind` expressions, which it will recognize and evaluate. However, in your example, you don't want that to happen. Instead, you want the nested `bind` to be forwarded as is to `call_handler`, which will then invoke it.

Boost provides [`boost::protect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_nested_binds_for_function_) which lets you mask the real type of the nested `bind` and thus prevent its evaluation by the outer `bind`.

Unfortunately, there is no [`std::protect`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18519087/241631) equivalent, but it's not difficult to [write it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520097/241631).

```
template<typename T>
struct protect_wrapper : T
{
    protect_wrapper(const T& t) : T(t)
    {}

    protect_wrapper(T&& t) : T(std::move(t))
    {}
};

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_bind_expression<std::decay_t<T>>::value,
                 T&&
                >
protect(T&& t)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_bind_expression<std::decay_t<T>>::value,
                 protect_wrapper<std::decay_t<T>>
                >
protect(T&& t)
{
    return protect_wrapper<std::decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Just wrap your inner `bind` expression with `protect`, and your code will compile.

```
auto b = protect(std::bind([&]() {}));
do_something(b);
do_something(std::move(b));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55f8380297b7a1c1)

Comment: Thank you! If I understand correctly, `bind` perfectly forwards the callable's arguments, but for any arguments that are passed to the callable by reference, those arguments are passed as lvalue references and never rvalue references--regardless whether the argument was bound as an lvalue or rvalue.

Comment: @Craig No, `bind` *always* passes bound arguments as lvalues, *never* as rvalues, regardless of whether the corresponding parameter type in the callable is lvalue/rvalue/forwarding reference. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084685/241631) another answer of mine that shows the ugliness involved in getting `bind` to `move` the bound argument when it passes it to the callable.

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me a lot. [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28509110/1094609) showing a similar workaround to the one you linked for getting `bind` to pass an argument as an rvalue. Overall, I now better appreciate why Scott Meyers advises us to prefer lambdas to `std::bind`.